# how can i save dateTime in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, hottowel

i am new to mongoDB and I am working on a hottowel Project with c#, c# drive + mongoDB and i am have a huge problem saving dateTime and time.

what is actually in mongoHQ:

```
   {
      creator: "yobro",
      expirationDate: {
        DateTime: ISODate("1-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        Ticks: 0
      },
      institution: null,
      adjustedStartTime: {
        DateTime: ISODate("1-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        Ticks: 0
      }
   }
```

my javascript:

```
   var jsonModel ={
      creator: "yobro",
      expirationDate: {
        DateTime: moment(2014-03-27).toISOString(),
        Ticks: 0
      },
      institution: null,
      adjustedStartTime: {
        DateTime: moment(2014-02-21).toISOString(),
        Ticks: 0
      }
   }
```

**c#:**

```
   this.startTime = new DateTime();
   this.adjustedStartTime = new DateTime();
```

with i post this json **creator** is saved but not the date how can i solve this?

Comment: See [the documentation for mongo json extensions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON).

Comment: You're saving strings instead of dates (`toISOString`). You should probably be saving `ISODate` or `Date` objects. From C#, any plain old `System.DateTime` object should be mapped correctly to a BSON date.